# Selenium, automação para sistema web

Tags: php, java, html, selenium-webdriver

Bom dia amigos, estou enfrentando uma dificuldade, onde meu objetivo é automatizar um processo de abertura de petições num intranet, o sistema não possui captcha porém da forma como foi desenvolvido não consigo manipular os objetos do DOM via js com Selenium, o sistema não possui APIs e o unico meio seria via robo, cria um robo para abrir petições em grande volume, vi também autoHotKey e Autoit porém, usando um pouco a cabeça chego a mesma conclusão, de que essas ferramentas afinal também precisam manipular as ações do browser via js. Segue o código fonte da página para entender o porque não consigo interagir com os elementos.

```
   <body onload="ScriptLoaded()" draghandler="BodyDrag" style="">
      <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="Toolbar">
         <div class="TBTopBarStatus">Modo actual: <span class="TBTopBarStatusMode"></span></div>
         <a class="btn TBTopBarBox" href="javascript:"><img class="tbright" src="../../../../resources/images/tb_right.gif" alt="Mostrar barra de herramientas"><img class="tbdown" src="../../../../resources/images/tb_down.gif" alt="Ocultar barra de herramientas"></a>
         <table class="Toolbar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="TBGroup TBGroup0" nowrap="">
                     <a class="searchsavechanges btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBsearchsavechanges">Guardar</div>
                     </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="TBGroup TBGroup1" nowrap="">
                     <a class="newsearch btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBnewsearch"><img src="../../../../resources/images/tb_search.gif" alt="Nueva búsqueda"> Nueva búsqueda</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="newrequest btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBnewrequest"><img src="../../../../resources/images/tb_request.gif" alt="Nueva petición"> Nueva petición</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="modifyall btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBmodifyall"><img src="../../../../resources/images/tb_modall.gif" alt="Modificar todo"> Modificar todo</div>
                     </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="TBGroup TBGroup2" nowrap="">
                     <a class="savedsearches btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBsavedsearches"> Búsquedas</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="advancedsearch btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBadvancedsearch">Búsqueda avanzada</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="clear btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBclear">Borrar</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="settodefaults btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBsettodefaults">Establecer valores predeterminados</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="statushistory btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBstatushistory">Historial de estado</div>
                     </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="TBGroup TBGroup3" nowrap="">
                     <a class="logout btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBlogout">Cerrar sesión</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="help btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBhelp">Ayuda</div>
                     </a>
                     <a class="home btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
                        <div id="TBhome">Inicio</div>
                     </a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div style="left: 100000px;" id="ResultsList">
         <div arentretstr="Mostrando {0} - {1} de {3}" arprefsstr="Preferencias" arrefstr="Actualizar" ardeselallstr="Cancelar selección" arselallstr="Seleccionar todo" arrepstr="Informe" arid="1020" artype="Table" ardbn="CustomResultsList" class="arfid1020 ardbnCustomResultsList" style="top:0; left:0; width:0; height:0;visibility:hidden;z-index:0;" arcols="" arcolws="" arcoldlen="" ardrill="1" arserver="@" arschema="@" armaxrows="0" ardtype="1" arcsize="0" arfixhdr="1" arselrows="0" arselinit="0" arselrefresh="0" arautofit="0" arsort="" arqual="{qual:&quot;&quot;, ids:[],extids:[]}">
            <img src="../../../../resources/images/menu_down.gif" alt="" class="TableSortImgUp" arindom="1"><img src="../../../../resources/images/menu_up.gif" alt="" class="TableSortImgDown" arindom="1">
            <div class="TableHdr">
               <table class="TableHdr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableHdrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableHdrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="TableInner"></div>
            <div class="TableFtr">
               <table class="TableFtr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableFtrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableFtrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="left: 100000px;" id="Splitter" draggable="1" dragoriginal="1">
      </div>
      <div id="FormContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 344px; top: 0px;">
         <div style="top:0;left:0;width:790;height:595">&nbsp;</div>
         <div arid="536870913" artype="Char" ardbn="Cliente" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870913 ardbnCliente" style="z-index:987;top:76; left:26; width:367; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870913" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 121px; height: 17px;">Cliente*</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870913" cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0; left:122; width:226; height:21;" armenu="PTS:Obtener-Cliente" mstyle="2" readonly="" mdd="1" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0; left:346; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="Menú para Cliente*">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870936" artype="Char" ardbn="Agrupacion" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870936 ardbnAgrupacion" style="z-index:992;top:108; left:26; width:364; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870936" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 121px; height: 13px;">Categoría Petición*</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870936" cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0; left:122; width:216; height:21;" armenu="PTS:Obtener-Agrupacion" mstyle="2" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0; left:343; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="Menú para Categoría Petición*">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870934" artype="Char" ardbn="Peticion_Servicio" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870934 ardbnPeticion_Servicio" style="z-index:986;top:141; left:27; width:566; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870934" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 120px; height: 17px;">Petición*</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870934" cols="20" maxlen="128" style="top:0; left:121; width:419; height:21;" armenu="PTS:Obtener-Peticion_Servicio" mstyle="2" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0; left:545; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="Menú para Petición*">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870914" artype="Char" ardbn="Entorno" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870914 ardbnEntorno" style="z-index:988;top:177; left:26; width:367; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870914" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 121px; height: 13px;">Entorno*</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870914" cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0; left:122; width:226; height:21;" armenu="PTS:Obtener-Entorno" mstyle="2" readonly="" mdd="1" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0; left:346; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="Menú para Entorno*">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870950" artype="Char" ardbn="Descripcion" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870950 ardbnDescripcion" style="z-index:1001;top:217; left:27; width:565; height:60;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870950" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 120px; height: 56px;">Descripción*</label><textarea readonly="" class="text " id="arid536870950" cols="20" maxlen="0" style="top: 0px; left: 121px; width: 418px; height: 60px; background-color: transparent;" rows="4" wrap="soft"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d expand" style="top:0; left:544; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_text.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:19; height:19;" alt="Editor para Descripción*">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870951" artype="EnumSel" ardbn="Urgencia" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870951 ardbnUrgencia" style="z-index:1002;top:286; left:309; width:256; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870951" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 120px; height: 17px;">Urgencia*</label>
            <div class="selection" style="top:0; left:121; width:135; height:21;" arselmenu="[{v:&quot;Low&quot;,l:&quot;Baja&quot;},{v:&quot;Medium&quot;,l:&quot;Media&quot;},{v:&quot;High&quot;,l:&quot;Alta&quot;},{v:&quot;Urgent&quot;,l:&quot;Urgente&quot;}]">
               <input id="arid536870951" class="text " readonly="" style="top:0; left:0; width:114; height:21;" type="text">
               <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0; left:114; width:21; height:21;">
               <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="">
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870941" artype="Char" ardbn="Requester Name+" ardcf="1" class="df  dfro arfid536870941 ardbnRequesterName+" style="z-index:995;top:372; left:40; width:310; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870941" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 107px; height: 17px; color: rgb(160, 160, 164);">Nombre</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870941" cols="20" maxlen="128" style="top:0; left:108; width:202; height:21;" readonly="" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870949" artype="Char" ardbn="Telefono" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870949 ardbnTelefono" style="z-index:1000;top:404; left:40; width:310; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870949" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 107px; height: 17px;">Teléfono*</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870949" cols="20" maxlen="30" style="top:0; left:108; width:202; height:21;" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870957" artype="Char" ardbn="Email" ardcf="1" class="df  dfro arfid536870957 ardbnEmail" style="z-index:1003;top:436; left:40; width:310; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870957" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 107px; height: 17px; color: rgb(160, 160, 164);">Email</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870957" cols="20" maxlen="100" style="top:0; left:108; width:202; height:21;" readonly="" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870958" artype="Char" ardbn="Departamento_People" ardcf="1" class="df  dfro arfid536870958 ardbnDepartamento_People" style="z-index:1004;top:468; left:40; width:310; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870958" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 107px; height: 17px; color: rgb(160, 160, 164);">Departamento </label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870958" cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0; left:108; width:202; height:21;" readonly="" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870945" artype="AttachmentPool" ardbn="Attachment Pool" class="arfid536870945 ardbnAttachmentPool" style="top:375; left:397; width:334; height:79;z-index:998;" arrows="[{f:536880912,l:&quot;Adjunto 1&quot;},{f:536880913,l:&quot;Adjunto 2&quot;},{f:536880914,l:&quot;Adjunto 3&quot;}]" arcol0="Nombre de Archivo" arcol1="Tamaño" arcol2="Etiqueta de adjunto" arcolw="111" aradd="Agregar" ardelete="Eliminar" ardisplay="Mostrar" arsave="Guardar en disco">
            <div class="TableHdr">
               <table class="TableHdr">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableHdrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableHdrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="TableInner"></div>
            <div class="TableFtr">
               <table class="TableFtr">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableFtrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableFtrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div style="visibility: hidden; width: 332px;" class="TableHdr">
               <table style="width: 332px;" class="TableHdr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableHdrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableHdrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div style="top: 0px; height: 57px; width: 332px;" class="TableInner">
               <div style="height: 55px; width: 330px;" class="BaseTableOuter" draghandler="BaseTable_DragHandler">
                  <div style="width: 333px; left: 0px;" class="BaseTableColHeaders">
                     <div style="left: 0px; width: 111px;" class="BaseTableHeader" draggable="1" artableid="536870945" ardatacol="0">Nombre de Archivo</div>
                     <div style="left: 111px; width: 111px;" class="BaseTableHeader" draggable="1" artableid="536870945" ardatacol="1">Tamaño</div>
                     <div style="left: 222px; width: 111px;" class="BaseTableHeader" draggable="1" artableid="536870945" ardatacol="2">Etiqueta de adjunto</div>
                     <div style="visibility: inherit; left: 105px;" dragoriginal="1" class="BaseTableBar" draggable="1" draghandler="BaseTable_DragHandler" artableid="536870945" arcolumnid="0">
                        <div></div>
                     </div>
                     <div style="visibility: inherit; left: 216px;" dragoriginal="1" class="BaseTableBar" draggable="1" draghandler="BaseTable_DragHandler" artableid="536870945" arcolumnid="1">
                        <div></div>
                     </div>
                     <div style="visibility: hidden; left: 327px;" dragoriginal="1" class="BaseTableBar" draggable="1" draghandler="BaseTable_DragHandler" artableid="536870945" arcolumnid="2">
                        <div></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="top: 16px; height: 39px; width: 330px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;" class="BaseTableInner">
                     <table title="" class="BaseTable">
                        <colgroup cols="3">
                           <col style="width: 111px;">
                           <col style="width: 111px;">
                           <col style="width: 111px;">
                        </colgroup>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr class="hiddentablehdr">
                              <th scope="col">Nombre de Archivo</th>
                              <th scope="col">Tamaño</th>
                              <th scope="col">Etiqueta de adjunto</th>
                           </tr>
                           <tr tabindex="0" arrow="0">
                              <td style="width: 107px;" scope="row" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;">Adjunto 1</nobr>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr tabindex="0" arrow="1">
                              <td style="width: 107px;" scope="row" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;">Adjunto 2</nobr>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr tabindex="0" arrow="2">
                              <td style="width: 107px;" scope="row" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;"></nobr>
                              </td>
                              <td style="width: 107px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                                 <nobr style="width: 107px;">Adjunto 3</nobr>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div style="top: 57px; width: 332px;" class="TableFtr">
               <table style="width: 332px;" class="TableFtr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableFtrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:" class="Agregar btn btn3d TableBtn ">Agregar</a><a style="visibility: hidden;" href="javascript:" class="Eliminar btn btn3d TableBtn">Eliminar</a><a style="visibility: hidden;" href="javascript:" class="Mostrar btn btn3d TableBtn">Mostrar</a><a style="visibility: hidden;" href="javascript:" class="Guardar en disco btn btn3d TableBtn">Guardar en disco</a></td>
                        <td class="TableFtrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <a href="javascript:" arid="536870910" artype="Control" ardbn="btn_Continuar" class="btn btn3d arfid536870910 ardbnbtn_Continuar" style="top:540; left:591; width:76; height:16;z-index:989;">
            <div class="btntextdiv" style="top:0; left:0; width:76; height:16;">
               <div class="f1" style="width: 76px;">Continuar</div>
            </div>
         </a>
         <a href="javascript:" arid="536870909" artype="Control" ardbn="btn_Cerrar" class="btn btn3d arfid536870909 ardbnbtn_Cerrar" style="top:540; left:671; width:57; height:16;z-index:991;">
            <div class="btntextdiv" style="top:0; left:0; width:57; height:16;">
               <div class="f1" style="width: 57px;">Cerrar</div>
            </div>
         </a>
         ardbnCliente
         <div arid="536870940" artype="Trim" arsubtype="3" ardbn="RequesterInformation_txt" class="arfid536870940 ardbnRequesterInformation_txt trimdiv" style="z-index:994;top:335; left:103; width:152; height:13;background-color:#ffffff;">
            <table style="top:0; left:0; width:152; height:13;" class="trimTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="color:#ff0000;" class="f9 trimJustl" valign="middle">Información&nbsp;del&nbsp;solicitante</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div arid="300196300" artype="Trim" arsubtype="3" ardbn="Page Title_txt" class="arfid300196300 ardbnPageTitle_txt trimdiv" style="z-index:999;top:12; left:33; width:300; height:23;background-color:transparent;">
            <table style="top:0; left:0; width:300; height:23;" class="trimTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="" class="f2 trimJustl" valign="middle">Petición&nbsp;de&nbsp;Servicio</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870944" artype="Trim" arsubtype="3" ardbn="txtAttachments" class="arfid536870944 ardbntxtAttachments trimdiv" style="z-index:997;top:335; left:535; width:68; height:14;background-color:transparent;">
            <table style="top:0; left:0; width:68; height:14;" class="trimTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="color:#ff0000;" class="f9 trimJustl" valign="middle">Adjuntos<br></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870977" artype="Table" ardbn="tb_task" class="arfid536870977 ardbntb_task" style="top:550; left:335; width:352; height:96;visibility:hidden;display:none;z-index:1;left:10000;" arcols="736870918,736870919,736870920,736870921,736870922" arcolws="71,71,71,71,68" arcoldlen="254,255,60,60,60" ardrill="1" arserver="@" arschema="CHG:GPEX_JF_TSKTEMP_GROUP" armaxrows="0" ardtype="0" arcsize="0" arselrows="0" arselinit="0" arselrefresh="0" arautofit="1" arautorefresh="1" arselallstr="Select All" ardeselallstr="DeSelect All" arentretstr="{2} entries returned - {3} entries matched" arnotrefstr="Table has not been loaded" arrefstr="Refresh" arprefsstr="Preferences" arrepstr="Report" arsort="" arqual="{qual:&quot;1\\1\\1\\1\\4\\1\\1\\536870924\\99\\536870913\\4\\1\\1\\4\\99\\536870936\\4\\1\\1\\260000031\\99\\536870934\\4\\1\\1\\536871070\\99\\536870914\\4\\1\\1\\536870999\\99\\536870962\\&quot;,ids:[536870936, 536870934, 536870962, 536870914, 536870913]}">
            <img src="../../../../resources/images/menu_down.gif" alt="" class="TableSortImgUp" arindom="1"><img src="../../../../resources/images/menu_up.gif" alt="" class="TableSortImgDown" arindom="1">
            <div class="TableHdr">
               <table class="TableHdr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableHdrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableHdrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="TableInner"></div>
            <div class="TableFtr">
               <table class="TableFtr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="TableFtrL" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                        <td class="TableFtrR" nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870988" artype="Char" ardbn="MyRecentRequests" ardcf="1" class="df arfid536870988 ardbnMyRecentRequests" style="z-index:1035;top:47; left:25; width:144; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870988" style="top:4; left:0; width:106; height:17;color:#000080;">Mis últimas peticiones</label><textarea class="text sr  dat" id="arid536870988" cols="20" maxlen="0" style="top:0; left:107; width:11; height:21;" armenu="PTS:btn_MyRecentRquest_Menu" mstyle="2" readonly="" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0; left:123; width:21; height:21;">
            <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/field_menu.gif" style="top:1; left:0; width:18; height:18;" alt="Menú para Mis últimas peticiones">
            </a>
         </div>
         <a href="javascript:" arid="536870907" artype="Control" ardbn="PROD_Buscar" class="btn btn3d arfid536870907 ardbnPROD_Buscar" style="top:138; left:639; width:74; height:24;z-index:1010;">
            <div class="btntextdiv" style="top:0; left:0; width:74; height:24;">
               <div class="f1" style="width: 74px;">Buscar</div>
            </div>
         </a>
         <div arid="536870984" artype="Char" ardbn="GroupingID" class="df arfid536870984 ardbnGroupingID" style="z-index:990;top:286; left:27; width:256; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870984" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 120px; height: 17px;">ID de Agrupación</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870984" cols="20" maxlen="30" style="top:0; left:121; width:135; height:21;" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div arid="536870939" artype="Trim" arsubtype="2" ardbn="Box" class="arfid536870939 ardbnBox bs0 trimBox" style="z-index:993;top:330; left:30; width:337; height:24;background-color:#ffffff;border-width:2;">
         </div>
         <div arid="536870943" artype="Trim" arsubtype="2" ardbn="Box4" class="arfid536870943 ardbnBox4 bs0 trimBox" style="z-index:996;top:330; left:395; width:334; height:24;background-color:#ffffff;border-width:2;">
         </div>
         <div arid="536870966" artype="Char" ardbn="Con_copia_a" class="df arfid536870966 ardbnCon_copia_a" style="z-index:1008;top:497; left:39; width:310; height:21;">
            <label class="label f1 do" for="x-arid536870966" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 107px; height: 17px;">Con copia a</label><textarea class="text sr " id="arid536870966" cols="20" maxlen="255" style="top:0; left:108; width:202; height:21;" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
         </div>
         <form name="testForm" id="testForm" method="post" target="_blank" action="http://entrypoint.produban.gs.corp/EPFEngine/entrypoint.jsp">
            <input name="requestId" id="requestId" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="numeroEmpleado" id="numeroEmpleado" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="idioma" id="idioma" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="sociedad" id="sociedad" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="nodo" id="nodo" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="id_externo_aux" id="id_externo_aux" value="" type="hidden">
         </form>
      </div>
      <div style="left: 100000px; visibility: hidden;" id="QueryBar" class="AdvancedSearchBar" arid="1005" artype="SearchBar">
         <label class="hidden" style="left:0;top:0;" for="arid1005">Barra de búsqueda avanzada</label>
         <table class="SearchBarOperators" width="100%">
            <tbody>
               <tr height="20">
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">(</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">)</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">"</a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">+</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">-</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">*</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">/</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">%</a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">=</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">!=</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">&lt;</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">&gt;</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">&lt;=</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">&gt;=</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">LIKE</a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">AND</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">OR</a></td>
                  <td class="SearchBarButtonCell"><a href="javascript:" style="text-align:center;position:static;width:28px;height:19px;padding-top:1px" class="btn btn3d">NOT</a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table class="SearchBarInput" width="100%">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width=""><textarea style="width:99%;height:21;" class="sr" cols="" rows="1" id="arid1005" wrap="off"></textarea></td>
                  <td width="70"><a href="javascript:" style="position:static;height:19px;width:70px;text-align:center" class="btn btn3d menu">Campos&nbsp;<img style="border:none" alt="" src="../../../../resources/images/menu_down.gif"></a></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <input id="ARState" style="visibility:hidden" type="text">
   </body>
```

Já tentei inserir js pelo selenium, "executeScript(script)" usar regex mas sem sucesso, não sei se foi feito em applet java, se souberem alguma outra forma de simular/automatizar isso agradeço.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Selenium WebDriver para criar a automação, ligado a uma linguagem de programação a sua escolha: ele meio que cria um robô programável à logica que você escrever para cumprir uma tarefa, executando (mas não necessariamente) scripts em js e clicando em elementos da tela através de seletores css ou xpath.

Comment: Afinal, se você consegue reconhecer a olho nu como clicar em cada um dos elementos disponíveis, você deve repassar essa lógica de seleçao ao selenium para criar a automação procurada: seja por seletores de tag, classes, id, e até mesmo texto, posição de elemento e css aplicado caso não haja outras alternativas viáveis

Comment: Na verdade você já tentou interagir com os elementos via xpath utilizando as palavras chaves como por exemplo o following, parent child, etc? dê uma olhada [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/vb_xpath.htm) e qualquer duvida pode mandar aqui que eu ajudo :)